# how to save a 2d numpy array into a text file

Tags: python, numpy

I have this following code where "final" is an array [ 2.    75.75  73.875 93.625  7.    29.369]

now, how do I save the reshaped 2d matrix "fin" as a .txt file.

and if it is saved as a text file, how do I get back the same as a matrix in a different program, where I open the text file

```
    fin = numpy.reshape(final,(-1,3))
    print(fin)
    print(fin[0][2])
```

output of above code

```
    [[ 2.    75.75  73.875]
     [93.625  7.    29.369]]
    73.875
```

Comment: Save as csv....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the file : you can use :
`np.savetxt("file.csv", final, delimiter=",")` .here's the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)  if you want to modify more parameters

To open it in another file :
`new_array = np.genfromtxt("file.csv", delimiter=",")` .here's the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following :)

`np.savetxt("final.csv", final, delimiter=",")`

Comment: I would be sincerely curious to hear the reasoning behind downvoting a correct answer :)